# Is possible to move a file to another domain without ftp details and upload file url?

Tags: php

like this..

```
<?php 
        $uploaddir = 'www.anotherdomain.com/uploads/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    >?
```

Is possible to move a file to another domain without ftp details and upload file url ?

Comment: Is the other domain on the same server? Then yes it's possible.

Comment: no daan .. i mean different servers